# How do I check what module an object is defined in?

Tags: julia

If I have an object (say a method, or a struct, or a Type, imported with `using`), how can I get the module it was originally defined in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`parentmodule`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.parentmodule) function. For example:

```
julia> parentmodule(rand)
Base

julia> parentmodule(versioninfo)
InteractiveUtils
```